# Program crashed while trying to delete[] a dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, string-literals

During one of my recent interviews, I was asked to implement and test a user defined version of memcpy() function in C++.

My code was something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

void my_memcpy(void* src, void* dest, size_t size)
{
    char* m_src = (char*)src;
    char* m_dest = (char*) dest;
    
    for (int i=0; i<size ; i++)
        *(m_dest+i) = *(m_src+i);
}

int main()
{
    char* source;
    char* destination;
    source = new char[20];
    destination = new char[20];
    
    source = "Hello";
    my_memcpy(source, destination,5);
    
    std::cout << destination << "\n";
    
    delete[] source;
    delete[] destination;

    return 0;
}
```

The program would run with a warning, but output correctly and then crash at the end.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdEhh.png)

When I commented out the delete[] source line, the program wasn't crashing anymore.
I still don't understand why delete[] source would lead to a crash.

Kindly help me in explaining this or guide me to some reference which can clarify the underlying concept.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with char \* and delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245553/problems-with-char-and-delete)

Comment: `source = "Hello";` shouldn't compile (from C++11 upwards, I think this part of the standard changed at one point?), because string literals are `char const[]`.

Comment: What did you learn when you ran your program using a memory checker (e.g. Valgrind)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program crashes because you aren't `delete[]`'ing the pointer you allocated with `new[]`.

```
char* source;
source = new char[20];
source = "Hello";
delete[] source;
```

You first assign `source` to a dynamic array of 20 chars, but then you change `source` to point at a string literal. A string literal isn't allocated with `new[]`, so `delete[]`'ing it crashes the program.

I suppose that when you wrote `source = "Hello";` what you were trying to do was copy the characters of `"Hello"` into the location pointed at by `source`, but that's not what that line of code actually does. It copies the pointer, not what is being pointed at.

Here's one way of correcting the code:

```
strcpy(source, "Hello");
```

This would also work:

```
memcpy(source, "Hello", 5+1); // +1 for null terminator
```

Both of these functions copy the characters, not the pointer.

Comment: This is a good explanation. But one should also take care of the fact that `"Hello"` is a 6 character literal because terminating `'\0'` is also a part of the string. Another caution need to be taken when working with strings. `source = new char[20];` only allocates memory which may already contain some data. Copying only 5 letters from `"Hello"` may leave the string unterminated and later reading it as a string may go beyond 20 chars allocated to it.

Comment: Thanks @John for the explanation and Remy for the edit. I got my mistake now.